# url-rewrite not working with slash

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, seo

i have a problem for url-rewrite

in my query in web.config is shown below :

```
    <rule name="show master">
      <match url="master/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-].+)/([^.]*)/([^.]*)/([^.]*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="View.aspx?x={R:1}&amp;y={R:2}&amp;w={R:3}&amp;s={R:4}&amp;n={R:5}" />
    </rule>
```

IF i call this url below is working

```
  https://mydomain/master/xx/yy/ww/ss/12-n
```

then i call this url below is not working

```
  https://mydomain/master/xx/yy/ww/ss/12-n/
```

i know about SLASH , but i need both url is working

Comment: i need one rewrite rules

Comment: because i have more 150 rule url-rewrite , then is not easy

Comment: yes i try , but conflict in another ruls , this is 6 step , in down rule 5 step and conflict

Answer (score 0):

Does this work with adding /?$ /? at end of RegEx

```
<rule name="show master"  stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="master/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-].+)/([^.]*)/([^.]*)/([^.]*)\/?$" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="View.aspx?x={R:1}&amp;y={R:2}&amp;w={R:3}&amp;s={R:4}&amp;n={R:5}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: please add stopProessing =true too

Comment: I think debugging and getting more information on what the url is actually transforming to might be of help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: i try "\/?$" and stopProessing =true , but not working

Comment: From your comment :yes i try , but conflict in another ruls , this is 6 step , in down rule 5 step and conflict      I think it would make sense to reorder this rule and place it on the top of conflicting rule.try may be at 1st position